# Expressjs req.params undefined but req.req.params defined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on a nodejs project express application. My route looks something like this:

```
router.get('/observe/:fileName', function(res, req){

    var reqFileName = req.params.fileName;

    console.log("GET /observe/" + reqFileName);
    res.end();

}
```

The problem is that if I do a GET request on `localhost/observe/myFile` the variable `reqFileName` is undefined because `req.params.fileName` is undefined. But inspecting(using node-inspector) the `req` I can see that the `req` has a property called `req` that has `params`. so `req.req.params.fileName` will give my parameter value. Is this normal ?

Comment: you could have wrote a mistaken `middleware` that is doing such modifications.

Comment: I'm using busboy for some form data handling but on another route not this one. Also .. I commented out the bodyParser middleware and no result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've got `res` and `req` backwards. Try this:

```
router.get('/observe/:fileName', function(req, res){

    var reqFileName = req.params.fileName;

    console.log("GET /observe/" + reqFileName);
    res.end();

}
```